# I accidentally committed sins during the Ramadan

Tags: ramadan

Assalamu alaikum.

I read Qur'an that it is translated in English. I never forgot that if a person who does bad, then good then bad then good then bad again, Allah will not forgive him/her.

I am a Muslim, and I respect Allah. I always worship Him. I pray 5 times a day. I am currently reading Qur'an even I do not understand original Arabic. I have problems with my life. I am the oldest sister of siblings. Schools did not let me to be in because I am deaf. They only allowed my sisters to be in because they can hear. 3 years later, I finally enrolled schools. My sisters graduated when they were about 17 years old except me. I finished when I was 22-23 years old (I wish I was 18 years old to graduate). I highly hoped that I would drive first but my sisters did first. They promised me to drive first, but I found out that they did first. I was furious of them. I ignored them; I sat back in front of her in her car. I saw she was using phone while driving, I took photos of them and I will show to my family. But my parents are on trip, so I showed to my uncle. Today, I realized I was impatient backbit, and jealous. I already know I was about to be patient next time but I accidentally ended up being impatient again. So many times. I repeat, remember Qur'an said Allah does not forgive if someone does good then bad for many times. Now, I feel too bad that I committed sins during the Ramadan. I feel like my sins cannot be removed during the Ramadan. I do not feel closer to Allah, just little bit. I have a feeling that He does not forgive me. I do not want to say sorry what I have done to my family. I am worried about what I have done. Should I say sorry to them so will Allah forgive me? Will He remove my sins? Will I not go to hell? If answer, please explain something or in Qur'an only, not hadith. I am worried so much. I am depressed little.

Comment: I don't recall an ayah which says if one does bad after good, Allah will not accept their repentance - my understanding is that refers to disbelief after belief, not sins. Allah accepts sincere repentance for all sins. See 39:53.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think God will not forgive you. As long as you're alive, you always have the opportunity to repent.

Comment: Also to remind you, http://quran.com/103 do good to your family and recommend them to do good, you be patient and recommend them to be patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Masha Allah that you started  <strike>reading</strike> *understanding* Qur'an by God's grace. Also glad that you realized your fault. :)

As [Ansari](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25215/i-accidentally-committed-sins-during-the-ramadan#comment43883_25215) has guessed, you could probably be referring to [Qur'an 3:90](http://quran.com/3/90), which was about hypocrisy.

But, I think this is probably what you're looking for.

> *But repentance is not [accepted] of those who [continue to] do evil deeds up until, when death comes to one of them, he says, "Indeed, I have repented now," or of those who die while they are disbelievers. For them We have prepared a painful punishment. - [Qur'an 4:18](http://quran.com/4/18)*

So, as [Erciyes](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25215/i-accidentally-committed-sins-during-the-ramadan#comment43884_25215) as suggested, you <strike>still</strike> have time now to repent. And you know what, the motto of the above the two Ayahs is, you must not repeat your mistake again. Also [this](http://quran.com/4/17).

> I feel like my sins cannot be removed during the Ramadan

Also remind yourself that the probability of Allah forgiving the sins is high in the month of Ramadan itself.

> I do not feel closer to Allah, just little bit

Read the understandable version of Qur'an more and more till you get that feeling. (If you don't understand an Ayah, you can always ask it [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/ask))

> I have a feeling that He does not forgive me

Yes, Allah wants us to be afraid of him, i.e. fear him and ask repentance abundantly.

> Should I say sorry to them so will Allah forgive me?

[Yes, you should, immediately](http://quran.com/42/37-43). It is said, that, you must forgive the evil done to you by other people, the same way you expect God to forgive you from your sins.

> Will He remove my sins? Will I not go to hell?

Hope so..... [Insha Allah](http://quran.com/5/18). But, do not repeat them again, and [do your best](http://quran.com/34/4).

> *Verily, Allah is Oft Forgiving - [Qur'an](http://quran.com/search?q=Forgiving)*

---

> please explain something or in Qu'ran only, not hadith

Tried to confine myself within Qur'an only. Please follow the links for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that despair is from Satan, so once you start to despair, you will start to think that you will never forgiven and the result is you will be less active in your prayers and doing good deeds.

> He said, "And who despairs of the mercy of his Lord except for those
>   astray?" 
>   [Quran 15:56](http://quran.com/15/56)

So first you need to stop being despair about Allah's mercy, Allah says in Quran

> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by
>   sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah
>   forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the
>   Merciful." [Quran 39:53](http://quran.com/39/53)