# Sex during fast due to lack of knowledge

Tags: ramadan, sawm, sex, kaffarah

I heard from a renowned scholar on TV that you are permitted to get intimate with and have sex with wife during fasting in ramadan but not more than once (thats what I understood / interprete he said).
So I was having some foreplay with my wife (*with the intention not to get discharched*), and meanwhile started intercorse (*important point is that I was doing it with the intention of not geting discharched and the scholar's opinion was in my mind that I'm allowed one time*), meanwhile I got too much excited and intentionally ejaculated inside her (*I did it intentionaly because the scholar's verdict was in my mind that I was permitted to do that one time*).

Please advice, keeping in mind my interpretation / understanding of that scholar's opinion in my mind at that time.

1. Did I break my fast?
2. Should I pay kaffara or offer qaza of that fast?
3. Did I do a sin? While I thought it was permitted one time?
4. Kaffara or qaza is to be offered by me only or by me and my wife both?

Comment: See also: "[repent & seeking forgiveness after cumming out during fast in ramadan](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/24960/9123)"

Comment: Thnx brother. But my query is a bit different n complicated. I did sex with my mind that i was doing a halal thing ( as per that scholar's opinion in my mind). I did not know that i was doing a forbidden thing.... Pls consider this as well

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) Please go through [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090824101842AAZWxon). You must follow the Hadith and do what's required and what you can do and alongside ask [repentance](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25220/9123) 3) Don't know 4) Not sure.

Answer (score 4):

> Did i break my fast?

Yes, your fasting for that day was broken.

> Shud i pay kaffara or offer qaza of that fast?

You have to do kaffara as the act of breaking the fast (intercourse) was intentional.

> Did i do a sin? While i thought it was permitted one time.

Not knowing is not an excuse. And Allah is All-Forgiver.

> Kaffara or qaza is to be offered by me only or by me n my wife both?

If your wife was also fasting, she will also have to do kaffara for herself.

Comment: to the 2nd question, it has to be followed in an order acc. to the [Hadith](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090824101842AAZWxon)

Comment: Thnx brother. Pls advice i was doing all that only on the advice of a renowned relegious scholar. Thts y i thought i ws doing right. Had i known i was doing a haram act i wud never had done that. pls also consider my intention n niyyat that i was doing it as per the islamic teachings

Comment: `Not knowing is not an excuse.` How so? Majority of Muslims (irrespective of worldly education) are **not** scholars. How would they *know* everything so that there is no excuse against them?

Comment: @Farhan: every Muslim is responsible for knowing the basics of Islam like prayers and fasting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did i break my fast?

   Ans: Yes.
2. Shud i pay kaffara or offer qaza of that fast?

   Ans: Yes, both, 60+1=61.
3. Did i do a sin? While i thought it was permitted one time.

   Ans: Yes.
4. Kaffara or qaza is to be offered by me only or by me n my wife both?

   Ans: by both of you. individually both of you should perform 60 continuous kaffara and one qaza roja.

Answer (score -1):

Intention is the Key :

> Call them by [the names of] their fathers; it is more just in the
>   sight of Allah . But if you do not know their fathers - then they are
>   [still] your brothers in religion and those entrusted to you. And
>   there is no blame upon you for that in which you have erred but [only
>   for] what your hearts intended. And ever is Allah Forgiving and
>   Merciful. 33:5

We need also to be careful :

> The Day their faces will be turned about in the Fire, they will say,
>   "How we wish we had obeyed Allah and obeyed the Messenger." And they
>   will say, "Our Lord, indeed we obeyed our masters and our dignitaries,
>   and they led us astray from the [right] way. 33:66-67

Try to repent.

With Peace

Comment: Thnx brother. In the light of quranic verse u mentioned pls advice me on my 4 questions keeping in mind my circumctances n knowkedge at that time. 
 1.Did i break my fast?
 2.Shud i pay kaffara or offer qaza of that fast?
 3.Did i do a sin? While i thought it was permitted one time.
 4.Kaffara or qaza is to be offered by me only or by me n my wife both

Comment: Pls also consider i was doing all that only on the advice of a renowned relegious scholar. Had i known that i ws doing a haram act, i wud never had done that

Comment: My dear brother as I said,  Intention is the Key. 
IMHO, since you didn't know, and you broke your fast (your wife also), then you should at LEAST fast another day (If you want to do more, then it's your choice and it's good for you). Also please be aware, as quoted, there is no excuse for "renowned" scholar in the light of the verses 33:66-67. So you need to repent and be sure to not take what scholars say as final word.
We need to make the effort and to check in the Quran by ourself what Allah has commanded in his Book Quran

Comment: thnx alot brother. Im really relievd now. Realy grateful to u for sparing ur time to answer me.