# What is the Islamic verdict on doing a haram thing considering it halal?

Tags: halal-haram, sin

What is Islamic verdict of doing a haram thing considering it halal due to lack of knowledge or due to misguidance by some scholar? To be more specific please guide me in this problem.

Related question: [Sex during fast due to lack of knowledge](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/sex-during-fast-due-to-lack-of-knowledge)

Answer (score 1):

Intention is the Key :

> Call them by [the names of] their fathers; it is more just in the
>   sight of Allah . But if you do not know their fathers - then they are
>   [still] your brothers in religion and those entrusted to you. And
>   there is no blame upon you for that in which you have erred but [only
>   for] what your hearts intended. And ever is Allah Forgiving and
>   Merciful. 33:5

But we need also to be careful :

> The Day their faces will be turned about in the Fire, they will say,
>   "How we wish we had obeyed Allah and obeyed the Messenger." And they
>   will say, "Our Lord, indeed we obeyed our masters and our dignitaries,
>   and they led us astray from the [right] way. 33:66-67

With Peace